# Logout angular app when user sing off from window (windows + L) or lock screen

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, web-services

I'm working on angular app where i have a requirement that when user signoff or log the screen from windows/mac system (In windows its Windows + L), application should redirect to login page.

Application UI have been developed in angular js and have used session based authentication. timeouts are configured well when timeout happens it redirects to login page. Backend api's are built in same codebase in java spring mvc.

As per latest requirement UI application should redirect to login page when window logout/signout happens by the user.

Please suggest to implement above from UI or java spring side.

Comment: when you log out of windows, the browser will close, so, no redirect is possible

Comment: I don't think the system will notify you about a 'screen locked' event. So this becomes https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/120872/how-should-a-developer-reject-impossible-requirements

Comment: @ShubhamPratapSingh create a session storage and refresh it whenever an API call is made, using the httpInterceptor, then check if the token exists at regular intervals, when the token gets deleted, logout the application!